# Is there similar external GUI Front End for TFS ? (Something like Tortoise for SVN)

Tags: user-interface, tfs, version-control

Some time ago I have found seemingly a wonderful option:

TortoiseSVN  --->>>  use --->>> SVN bridge --->>> reach --->>> TFS.

https://svnbridge.codeplex.com/

But I am afraid, this rather not native solution, could possibly lead to hazard states, or incompatibilities. 
Especially between various versions of TFS and TortoiseSVN.

What does the community think of SVN bridge ?
Or is there any converged external F-E GUI client developed directly for TFS ? (Outside of VSO Team Explorer itself, or other integrated plugins for IntelliJ, Eclipse ...)

I really want an external tool, independent of any IDE.

Here is a list of pretty outdated offered solutions.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrod/2008/04/28/external-team-foundation-server-tools/

Comment: Any experiences/comments regarding SVN Bridge ?

Comment: The SVN bridge was built exclusively to support Subversion for the (now shuttered) Codeplex.  Although some efforts were made to make it work more generally, it is challenging to get working at all, and it is not recommended or supported.

Comment: @Edward:
Thank you for your hints. Indeed, it is challenging to get working..

Answer (score 3):

The [VS-TFS Power tools offer a Windows Explorer integration for VSTS/TFS](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power). It requires Team Explorer 2015 to be installed (or at least the TFS Client Object Model) and since the last version was never updated for VS2017, you need the 2015 Client object model present.

There is also the TFS/VSTS plugin for Eclipse called [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) and [Native support for TFVC in most JetBrains tools](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-visual-studio-team-services).

On top of that Team Explorer Everywhere ships with a cross-platform command line version of "tf", the standard version of "tf" is of course already an option to consider.

I'm not sure why you consider Team Explorer to be "dependent on any IDE" the Visual Studio Shell it ships with can just be fully ignored, just open the Source Control Explorer and the Team Explorer tab and you have a TFVC UI.

Comment: Are you saying that you do not need to install VisualStudio to use its TeamExploder ?
Frankly, I would prefer anything else than TE. 
(Personally, I find it not intuitive. I have already worked with SVN, GIT, ClearCase, MKS, SourceSafe, Plugins and stand alone GUIs and I could so far cope with anything. Suprisinly enough, I just do not cope quite well with TE & TFS. It has been > 1/2 a year now.)

Comment: Team Explorer comes with a separate installer which basically installs the "VS Shell", so a version of VS that only has the Team Explorer features enabled. Making it lightweight: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/?q=team+explorer

Comment: Nope I haven't tried it, I had no idea anything like that is available ;)

Comment: Well, I have installed the famous VS-TFS Power tools, and ? Nothing happens. I can see it among installed products, but win exploder context menu is not extended for TFS actions (as with TortoiseSVN), neither in VS TeamExplorer the TFS menu is extended.. What now. Shall I clean my win registers manually ? :D

Comment: Do you also have Team Explorer 2015 installed? That is required unfortunately. You may be able to get it working by dropping the contents of the TFS Client Object Model Nuget in the folder the object model is installed. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/14.102.0

Comment: Thanks Jesse, much better now.
I got the "TFS TE everywhere" thanks to the installed NuGet.
I am tempted to check yours as THE answer, however I was originaly seeking for something rather different than what I already have within VSO. May be this extension will ultimately match what I need.